# How to map an property of ClassA to one of SuperclassA?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pointers

I have a class named `SuperclassA`, and an class named `ClassA`. `ClassA` inherits from `SuperclassA`.

`SuperclassA` has got an property called `something`, so a very generic not-much-saying name. In `ClassA`, I want to have an property which maps to that `something` of `SuperclassA`.

How could I do that? I want to make absolutely sure that any access to `myBetterProperty` results in accessing what's behind `something`.

Assigning an value to `myBetterProperty` should result in assigning one to `something`, and vice versa.

How to? Pointers set up in init? How would that look like?

`*self.myBetterProperty = &something;` ? I'm not sure about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare in your .h:

```
@property(...) ... myBetterProperty;
```

and in your .m:

```
@synthesize myBetterProperty = something;
```

Comment: Error: Property myBetterProperty attempting to use ivar something declared in xxxxxx.h?

Comment: is `something` declared as @private?

Comment: well, it's just declared. no keywords. I guess then it's private...?